# What's the best way to make my app available on Google Play in countries without payment support?

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, android-gradle-plugin

I have a free app with in-app purchases on Google Play. Google treats it as "paid" and disallows downloads from selected locations (e.g. China, Cuba).

I want to publish a "Free" version of the app, without in-app purchases, just for these markets and use the same store listing.

I've experimented with [multiple APK mode](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html), and the "uses-feature" [Play Store filter](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) to serve the proper binary based on the support for payments. It seems that I need something like this in my Gradle build file:

```
productFlavors {
     withoutPayments {
         versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode
     }
     withPayments {
         versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 1
         # More code that adds the
         # <uses-feature android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" android:required="true" />
         # to the Manifest.
     }
}
```

Would this solve the problem? If yes, what would be the correct Gradle config?

Comment: For the record, here's a page that lists countries where there's no support for paid apps: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286 .

Comment: You could try using `required="false"`

Comment: @StenSoft Will experiment with it. Did you try it yourself or know a project that uses this?

Comment: @StenSoft I've added a related question, could you reply there if you know? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142648/can-i-use-uses-feature-instead-of-uses-permission-with-com-android-vending

Comment: I don't know, it was just an idea.