# Can I use "uses-feature" instead of "uses-permission" with "com.android.vending.BILLING"?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

In my app's AndroidManifest.xml I currently have

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Is it possible to replace it with:

```
<uses-feature android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" android:required="false" />
```

?

I'm assuming that as a result my app would appear in both countries with payments support and in those without. In the latter, in-app purchases would simply not work.

When uploading the APK with said modifications, Google Play warns:

> "You uploaded an APK that does not have BILLING permission, or has a
>   BILLING permission that is limited to specific sdk versions. BILLING
>   permission is required for selling in-app products."

Should I ignore it, and still assume that purchases will be available in supported markets?

Comment: As sais on the warning: "BILLING permission is required for selling in-app products". So your app will still work but you won't be able to let the user buy things (features?)

Comment: I too would like an answer on this.

Comment: Has anyone been able to resolve this? Providing an app (with BILLING permission in Manifest) in countries which do not support Google Wallet payments?

Comment: @Andrew did this solution work?